# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

This is a fun that updates my UI 
the error is the following :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In the following code:

```
func updateUI() {
    self.questionDisplay.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].question
    self.suggestion1.titleLabel?.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].suggestion[0] // Here is the error

    self.suggestion2.titleLabel?.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].suggestion[1]
    self.suggestion3.titleLabel?.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].suggestion[2]
    self.suggestion4.titleLabel?.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].suggestion[3]

    self.suggestion5.titleLabel?.text = self.model.questions[model.selector].suggestion[4]
    scoreDisplay.text = "\(score)"
}
```

Comment: pls check if model, questions are not empty.

Comment: i've already initialized the model, and the type of question, answers... are String, not String?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing here and for me the solution was as follows.

Every now and than I put my own variables and expressions into the debugging area to see right away if their values are correct. Some of those expressions had "unvalid expression" as result. Removing all of these "unvalid expression" solved the problem. The error doesn´t come up anymore.

Hope this helps